# Unity change background color with GvrMain (VR) Camera

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, google-cardboard, google-vr-sdk

I am working with the Google VR SDK for Unity, and I want to change the background color of my scene from the original blue to solid white. I have attempted adding a Camera component and a Skybox component to the GvrMain camera, but with no luck. How can I achieve this? (If programming is required, I am using C#). Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Unity Main Camera for Google cardboard.

In camera component of Main camera

> - set clear flags to solid color(It will be Skybox by default)
> - change the background to white